# How to do you call to LMS from Captivate 8

Tags: scorm

How do you send user variables / data to the LMS from captivate 8?

Have tried following but no luck:

to send data:

```
document.getElementById('Captivate').SCORM_CallLMSSetValue("cmi.core.lesson_status", "Passed");
```

to retrieve data:

```
var str = document.getElementById('Captivate').SCORM_CallLMSGetValue("cmi.core.lesson_status");
```

display retrieved data in captivate:

```
window.cpAPIInterface.setVariableValue("lessonStatus", str );
```

> captivate shows result as: 0

Any help would be appriacated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Captivate 8 uses SCORM Driver for it's SCORM tracking. Here's the [documentation for SCORM Driver](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-driver/scorm-driver-documentation/?utm_source=scorm_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=scorm_driver_documentation?pmc=em-1).

Comment: actually the above calls to the LMS is based the scomr driver the captivate is using...

Comment: have you pinned down where the error is occurring e.g. what does window.cpAPIInterface.setVariableValue("lessonStatus", 1); or window.cpAPIInterface.setVariableValue("lessonStatus", "foo"); do?